# Cloning Mercurial Repositories from C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mercurial, clone, checkout

I am writing an application that will allow users to schedule repeating tasks that download/package up files from any number of sources (SVN/Mercurial/etc).

I have managed to implement everything except for Mercurial. As I want my application to handle everything, I would like to avoid having to distribute the entire Mercurial directory with my application, or worse, requiring the user to have it installed.

I have not been able to find any sort of API for it, so I am wondering what the best approach would be. Is there a standalone executable I could include with my project, and use that when my application issues an "hg clone" command?

Comment: Related question: [Using Mercurial (HG) programmatically from C#/.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885958/using-mercurial-hg-programmatically-from-c-net) (albeit older).

Comment: Thanks, although I already stumbled across that and didn't find it all that helpful. I did check out http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com but it has no install help, so I can't tell if I still need to include mercurial .exe with application, or whats going on there.

Comment: It has source code, so hopefully once CodePlex's Mercurial integration starts working again it'll help you out. Upon second look at the [Features](http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Home) page, `Note: Requires Mercurial to be installed, library does not come with Mercurial executables and does not function on its own!` so it may not be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, thank you for pointing that out. Yeah the main issue is that I can't require Mercurial be installed as that defeats the purpose. I might have to look into some other alternatives for the time being.

Comment: Mercurial.net requires the mercurial client installed, or at least bundled with your application, it only makes it easy to execute hg.exe and process the results (disclaimer: I'm the author of Mercurial.Net)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this page - [MercurialApi](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi).

The recommended API is actually the command line and it starts with reasons why you shouldn't use the internal API.

However, it does have a lot of info on how to use the internal API if you really want to.

You'd need to find some way to call Python from C#. One that I found when looking into doing something like this was called [IronPython](http://ironpython.net).

Also, I'm pretty sure that your program would have to be open source if you were to use Mercurial's internal API but you'd need to look
Into that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to interface with Mercurial is through the [command server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer).

Basically the command server is similar to the command line, but avoids the Mercurial instantiation overhead. There is a Java (JavaHg) and a Python implementation (PythonHgLib), a C# version of it does not exist yet I think but it shouldn’t be too complex to implement, the communication protocol is designed to be simple.

Otherwise, invoking the command line is the recommended approach.